# Javascript sub-methods

Tags: javascript, nested

I'm trying to learn Javascript.  I'm making a grocery list that adds, removes, tallies, and clears items.  The parts that work are all from previous stack overflow advice.  The more I work with it the less I understand why any of it works. I just went through the codeacademy JS track again but it's not matching what I'm doing here.

I'm down to the last two methods: tallying prices & searching for an item to return its properties.  When I alter these methods to try and do something simple like print out a number, that won't even work. Ruby was nowhere near this painful to learn.  I'll take any advice on understanding JS or how and why my remaining methods are not working.

```
var groceryList = function(food, quantity, price) {
    this.items = [];
    this.items.push({food:food, quantity:quantity, price:price});

    var currentList = this;
    this.addStuff = function(food, quantity, price) {
        currentList.items.push({food:food, quantity:quantity, price:price});
        return currentList.items;
    };

    this.tallyList = function() {
        return currentList.items.length;
    };

    this.getItems = function() {
        return currentList.items;
    };


// BROKEN - always returns 'not on list' - the matching bit does not work
    this.onList = function(someItem) {
      for(var key in currentList) {
        console.log(currentList[key] === someItem); // t/f
        if(currentList.items === someItem) {
          return currentList[key];
        }
        else {
          return "not on list"
        }
      }
    };

// BROKEN -the simplest of commands here will not print.  WTF?
    this.whatWillItCost = function() {
        mySum = 0;
        for(i = 0; i < currentList.items.length; i++) {
          mySum += currentList.items.price;
        }
        return mySum;
    };

    this.goShopping = function() {
        currentList.items = {};
        return currentList.items;
    };
};



//TESTS

var myList = new groceryList("cookie", 2, 1.00);
console.log(myList);
myList.addStuff("brownie", 1, 2.50);
console.log(myList);
console.log(myList.tallyList());
console.log(myList.onList("cookie")); // must fix - always returns false
console.log(myList.whatWillItCost) // must fix - totally broken
console.log(myList.goShopping());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for the first function, you are referencing the class instead of the items of the list(which you do well in your second), so it should be:

```
this.onList = function(someItem) {
  for(i = 0; i < currentList.items.length; i++) {
    if(currentList.items[i].food === someItem) {
      return currentList.items[i]
    }
    else {
      return "not on list"
    }
  }
};
```

As for your second, only mistake is missing the reference to the index of items list:

```
mySum += currentList.items[i].price; // should it be * currentList.items[i].quantity?
```

You also need to change:

```
console.log(myList.whatWillItCost()) // without the () you are displaying the reference to the function instead of executing it
```

Js Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3a4ebdpz/

You could also make your onList function a bit shorter this way using `Array.filter`:

```
this.onList = function(someItem) {
    var results= currentList.items.filter(function(item){ 
        return item.food===someItem;
    })
    return results.length == 0 ? 'not on list' : results[0]
};
```

Answer (score 0):

it's working , "I'm down to the last two methods: tallying prices & searching for an item to return its properties" has been fixed.

PFB code ,

```
<html>
<body>
<script>
var groceryList = function(food, quantity, price) {
    this.items = [];
    this.items.push({food:food, quantity:quantity, price:price});

    var currentList = this;
    this.addStuff = function(food, quantity, price) {
        currentList.items.push({food:food, quantity:quantity, price:price});
        return currentList.items;
    };

    this.tallyList = function() {
        return currentList.items.length;
    };

    this.getItems = function() {
        return currentList.items;
    };


// BROKEN - always returns 'not on list' - the matching bit does not work
    this.onList = function(someItem) {
      for(var key in currentList.items) {
        console.log(currentList.items[key].food === someItem); // t/f
        if(currentList.items[key].food === someItem) {
          return currentList.items[key];
        }
        else {
          return "not on list"
        }
      }
    };

// BROKEN -the simplest of commands here will not print.  WTF?
    this.whatWillItCost = function() {
        mySum = 0;
        for(i = 0; i < currentList.items.length; i++) {
          mySum += currentList.items[i].price;
        }
        return mySum;
    };

    this.goShopping = function() {
        currentList.items = {};
        return currentList.items;
    };
};



//TESTS

var myList = new groceryList("cookie", 2, 1.00);
console.log(myList.items);
myList.addStuff("brownie", 1, 2.50);
console.log(myList.items);
console.log(myList.tallyList());
console.log(myList.onList("cookie")); // must fix - always returns false
console.log(myList.whatWillItCost()) // must fix - totally broken
console.log(myList.goShopping());
</script>
</body>
</html>
```